# How to put an image/icon before select option text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Looking to place different icons in front of items/options in a HTML select box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In theory, you could make use of the CSS `background-image` property in the `<option>` element, but that doesn't work flawlessly in (*cough*) IE.

Best what you can do is to use jQuery/Javascript to mimic a dropdown with a bunch of `<li>` or `<div>` elements. As far no one comes to mind (I've never had the need for such a dropdown), but you can find [here](http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/03/11-jquery-plugins-to-enhance-html-dropdowns/) an overview of the "better" jQuery dropdown plugins, there must be one which suits your needs, for example [this one](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown).

Comment: +1... but I thought IE was supporting this now? (I'm not sure, though) I do know that IE supports changing the background color of options a little better than other browsers, so I guess I figured background-image would be supported.  [shrug]

Comment: My first instinct was the same, to use the CSS background-image property, however Safari 4.0, Opera 10, Chrome 3.0 and (of course) IE do not support this, while FF does.  I also agree that a dhtml approach may be the best approach here, thank you for the links.

Comment: test code..
<select multiple>
      <option id="1" style="background-image:url('images/online.jpg');background-repeat:no-repeat;padding-left:21px;height:21px">Item 1</option>
      <option id="2">Item 2</option>
    </select>

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do it would be to dynamically replace the select with a DHTML dropdown, the vanilla  control doesn't have that capability. Using a DHTML dropdown has the benefit that it should degrade gracefully for those with javascript disabled.

You could do it quite simply with jQuery, have your normal <select>, grab it and replace with a hidden field, have your fancy DHTML dropdown with images (hidden positioned <div> with an unordered list could do it), attach to the onclick event of the items and make that update the hidden field with the selected value.